# Unable to iterate through boost unordered hashmap

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost unordered hashmap and I'm having a difficulty looping through all the keys in the hashtable.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

struct Record
{
        char *data;

};

typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Record*> > MAP;

struct OuterRelation
{
        short num_keys;
        short join_key_ndx;
        MAP hash_table;
};


Record *new_record = malloc(sizeof(Record));
new_record->data = "some string";
char *key = new_record->data;
(outer_relation->hash_table)[key].push_back(new_record);

/* print all keys in the hash table */
BOOST_FOREACH(MAP::value_type pair, outer_relation->hash_table)
{
       std::string key  = pair.first;
       ...
}
```

The program fails at the foreach loop. Is there are problem with the elements I'm adding to the hash table?

Comment: Do you have a backtrace? One potential problem is that the Record's constructor is not called in your code. This should be ok, while it's only member is a pointer, however if you add some type with a nontrivial constructor to it, that will be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is C++ **STOP USING `malloc`**. (C++ uses `new` and `delete`. Although: don't use those either. Use `std::make_unique` and perhaps `std::make_shared` or `std::vector<T>`).

---

Having said that, here's why: C has no classes. C only has POD-type `struct`s.

As long as you guarantee this in your C++ code, you can "get away" with C-isms. Here's a C++ generic function that does the malloc trick ***with checks***:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* make_memory_leak(Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "undefined behaviour for non-POD types");

    T* raw = static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T)));

    static_assert(boost::proto::is_aggregate<T>::value, "aggregate initialization required");
    *raw = { std::forward<Args>(args)... };

    return raw;
}
```

So now you can just say

```
auto record_ptr = make_memory_leak<Record>("some string");
```

and you'll have the equivalent of

```
Record* record_ptr = static_cast<Record*>(malloc(sizeof(Record)));
*record_ptr = { "some string" }; // aggregate initialization
```

So, here's your test code, working: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/509cdacad5e503fa)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/traits.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Record {
    char const* data;
};

typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Record*> > MAP;

struct OuterRelation
{
    short num_keys;
    short join_key_ndx;
    MAP hash_table;
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
T* make_memory_leak(Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "undefined behaviour for non-POD types");

    T* raw = static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T)));

    static_assert(boost::proto::is_aggregate<T>::value, "aggregate initialization required");
    *raw = { std::forward<Args>(args)... };

    return raw;
}

int main()
{
    auto outer_relation = std::make_shared<OuterRelation>();
    for (auto key : { "some string", "some other string", "which", "by the way", "are", "const char(&)[]" })
        outer_relation->hash_table[key].push_back(make_memory_leak<Record>(key));

    /* print all keys in the hash table */
    BOOST_FOREACH(MAP::value_type pair, outer_relation->hash_table)
    {
        std::cout << pair.first << "\n";
    }
}
```